# Rails gem not using environment variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, environment-variables

I have created a Rails gem and a Rails app that uses that gem. The gem is deployed at Gemfury, and I successfully am able to `bundle install` the gem. In the gem, I have a variable set to an environment variable. When I run my app locally, the places in the app that use environment variables are able to read my environment variables (managed by Figaro), but the gem is not able to. What might I be missing or doing wrong?

For example if I do this in the gem:

```
 cache_enabled = ENV['CACHE_ENABLED'] || false
```

It will end up as false even if my environment variable CACHE_ENABLED = true. My Rails app reads environment variables with no problem.

I'm using Rails 4 if that makes a difference.

Comment: So, the environment variables are set locally, yes?  Where is the production app located?

Comment: Can you verify that the environment you're setting the variable in is the same that you're running the library in?

Comment: @Mallanaga I'm setting the environment variables locally and running locally. When I go to production, I'll put it up in Heroku and set the Heroku environment variables.

Comment: @zeantsoi If I'm running the Rails app that specifies gems in its Gemfile, those gems are running in the same environment as the app right?

Comment: please add debug lines: `p ENV['CACHE_ENABLED'].class`, and `p cache_enabled` after the codeline. and show us a result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails 4.1 or above then it's probably [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring).

You should be able to `$ spring stop`, then run your app correctly (as spring will restart with the new env vars).

You can remove spring permanently per [this](https://github.com/rails/spring#removal).

---

As a side note, I tend to use [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) locally (including the lesser known `foreman run`) command, if you do that then you can prepend `DISABLE_SPRING=1` to your `.env`s and Spring will be bypassed whenever you use Foreman.